# SQL: Print out a name in a table only once

Tags: sql

I am trying to list the customer names who placed an order, who are from a certain county and placed order from a certain sales rep. The problem is, the final table prints out their names several times. How do I get them to print out the names only once each?

```
SELECT cName
FROM customer INNER JOIN orders ON customer.cNo = orders.cNO,author
WHERE county = "Galway" AND saleRepName = "Jane Smith";
```

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT cName ...`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? (`"Galway"` is a non-standard way of specifying a string literal - SQL uses single quotes to denote a string literal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Distinct` but you might take a performance hit if there are a lot of records

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    cName 
FROM customer 
    INNER JOIN orders ON customer.cNo = orders.cNO,author 
WHERE county = "Galway" AND saleRepName = "Jane Smith";
```

`Group By` might be faster with the added benefit of allowing you to get a count:

```
SELECT
    count(1),
    cName 
FROM customer 
    INNER JOIN orders ON customer.cNo = orders.cNO,author 
WHERE county = "Galway" AND saleRepName = "Jane Smith";
GROUP BY cName
```

This will print out something like:

```
3 John Doe
6 Jane Smith
1 Jersey Mike
```

Comment: Should that be `count(cName)`?

Comment: Doesn't matter. `count(1)`, `count(cName)` and `count(*)` will all produce the same output. Whatever DBMS he's using is smart enough to optimize it as well.

Comment: Huh, didn't know about `count(1)`